# Remove innerHTML img completely by jQuery selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've dinamically created a div with the code below:

```
typebox.innerHTML += "<div id='idtypebox' class='typebox'><img id='typeImg' width='30px' height='30px' src="+d[o].src+"></div>";
```

My intention is to remove completely the innerHTML I created, by changing the innerHTML that had created the img and if change the form A to B, those images will be removed.

```
function SelectCheck() {
  var select_val = $('#Check').val();
  // using this to remove typeimg
  var toRemove = document.getElementById('typeImg');
  toRemove.parentNode.removeChild(toRemove);
  if (select_val) {
    ajax_json_gallery("Img/"+select_val);
  }
  return;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Check").change(SelectCheck).change();
});
```

I tried this code by on button and it works, but if I put in jQuery selection I get an error

```
var toRemove = document.getElementById('typeImg');
toRemove.parentNode.removeChild(toRemove);
```

Comment: did you initialize event after appending html in the dom ??

Comment: $("#idtypebox").html(" ");  OR   $("#typeImg").remove();  both should work..

Comment: if i put the code in , those img wont created at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just :

```
$("#typeImg").remove();
```

And the complete code :

```
function SelectCheck(){
    var select_val = $('#Check').val();
    // using this to remove typeimg
    $("#typeImg").remove();
    if(select_val){
      ajax_json_gallery("Img/"+select_val);
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

             myVar=$("#d1 [href]").html();
                var href = $(myVar).attr('src');
                $("#d1").html('');
                $("#d1").html('<img src="'+href+'" class="images_responsive_mode">').removeAttr("href");

                });

    </script>
```

this is one of the script which i created for remove the class assigned by wordpress and to assign new class for responsive image , if it useful for you do this !

Answer (score 0):

you can use childNodes to remove the innerHtml

```
var toRemove = document.getElementById('typeImg');
            toRemove.parentNode.removeChild(toRemove.childNodes[0])
```